# Maintaining aspect ratio of of iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an iframe that I want to maintain the aspect ratio at 16:9 (height/width) right now there is an box below the iframe that I don't want the iframe to ever overlap. So I can't use the padding bottom trick because it causes the video to overlap the box. How can I get the maximum width and height that the iframe can attain in the remaining space?

So for example let's say I have a window that is 1200px by 600px, 50px is used for a box. I want the iframe to take the maximum width and height on the remaining 1200px by 550px and still keep its aspect ratio and not ever go below the box at the bottom of the page. How can I do that using jquery? Also as the window resizes the iframe should keep its aspect ratio

I'm asking for the formula that embedded videos use to maintain their aspect ratio in an iframe. When I embed an iframe that has a video in it the video always maintains its aspect ratio by adding black boxes around it.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="iframe-container">
    <iframe></iframe>
</div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: 2 requests, sir. 1. please provide code, 2. is this box where? X and Y? Is it in the center? 50%, 50% Is it in the corner? 100% 0? If so which corner? 0 100%?, 100% 100%? See this is utterly futile without code. All of that describing without providing accurate data in the form of code is silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintaining an aspect ratio is pretty straightforward with some conditional math, over time.

> Generally, we have a container, a thing contained, and a known ratio (16/9). The height or the width can be determined by trapping the thing in the container (checking for out of bounds) and computing the other value from the ratio.
>
> **Update** : once you have the new values, check for out of bounds. In this case, a min height and a max width.

A bit like so:

```
 // if the iframe height (container width / ratio) is greater than the container height
 if ( (cW / RATIO) > cH){
 
    h = cH;             // set the height equal to the container
    w = cH * RATIO;     // set the width equal to the container height * ratio
 } else {
 
    w = cW;             // set the width equal to the container
    h = cW / RATIO;     // set the height equal to the container width / ratio
 }

 // Ok so, now that the iframe is scaled up, check for out of bounds
 if ( iH < MIN_HEIGHT ){
  
   iH = MIN_HEIGHT;     // set the height to the const
   iW = iH * RATIO;     // use the same basic formula, but use the new value
 }
  
 if (iW > MAX_WIDTH){

   iW = MAX_WIDTH;      // set the width to the const
   iH = iW / RATIO;     // same formula, new value
 }
```

[- Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/51uckd45/2/) with some discussion.
[- Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/51uckd45/3/) with some out of bounds checks.

You can, obviously, work some extra math into the computation to make space for a control bar, or whatever. This is just the basic principle, in a very simple state. I almost always have some additional checks against max width, or do some positioning or whatever. But this should be a good start.

Cheers -

Comment: What's the 
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));?

Comment: oh - I just have the whole thing running on a resize event, and that triggers an initial event. same as the jQ $().trigger('event'); But you know - lets not use jquery. its really not needed much any more.

Comment: how can I set a maximum width of 1280 and minimum height of 400 on the container

Comment: hey why don't you give that a shot yourself. I set you up with a basic pattern and some math. Now, make secondary checks on the two iframe props (h/w), setting the desired values if they are out of bounds.

Comment: @BrownKL - have any luck setting max values?

Comment: sure thing. So - check my update. This should give you some direction. And just as a sidebar - web dev stuff like this is often just about tinkering with an issue until it works. Tinker long enough and you won't have to guess any more. Cheers -

Comment: What do you mean by "out of bounds"?

Comment: if you have a max width of 100px, the algorithm determines the element should be 101px, its out of bounds.

Comment: I'm sure I saw "run this javascript code on first page load" in the jsfiddle but I must have that confused with some other example that I saw. Is it possible to trigger the script during the first page load?

Comment: Found it. https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php // When the window is resized
$(window).resize(function() { ......... }).resize(); // Kick off one resize to fix all videos on page load. Is it possible to add this to your example?

Comment: since this is done without jquery, you'd have to use the body.onload method, or something like that. You're just trying to prevent the script from running until everything is loaded.

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty straightforward and can be done with CSS, if you know the expected aspect ratio. For video embeds at 16:9 (56.5%), it's done like this.

You can add `max-height` and `max-width` properties to the container just as you would any other element. The height is 0 and the padding is simply set according to the aspect ratio you want. The iframe is set to fill the container width and height so it will conform to the aspect ratio based on the padding.

```
.iframe-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.5%;
    height: 0;    
}
.iframe-container iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

> **Update:** You can do this much better with `vw` units.
>
> This will work if your iframe is intended to be the full width of the browser. Otherwise you can do some calculations on it. But, for a full width iframe that you want to preserve aspect ratio on, it goes as follows (for 16:9 aspect ratio):

```
iframe {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 56.5vw;
}
```